# Deduce 1d wave equation from 2d by method of descent

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

Suppose we take as given that the formula for the wave equation on $\mathbb{R}^2$ is

$$u(x,t) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{|y-x|<t} \frac{g(y)}{\sqrt{t^2-|y-x|^2}}dy+ \frac{d}{dt}\left\{  \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{|y-x|<t} \frac{f(y)}{\sqrt{t^2-|y-x|^2}}dy  \right\},$$

where $u=f(x)$ at $t=0$, and $u_t=g(x)$ at $t=0$. We want to deduce the 1d wave equation by the method of descent. This is how I understand the method of descent: suppose $u(x,t)$ solves $u_{xx}=u_{tt}$ on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $u=f(x)$ at $t=0$, and $u_t=g(x)$ at $t=0$. Extend $f$ and $g$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ by making their values independent of the $x_2$ coordinate.

Then I end up with

$$u(x,t) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{|y-x|<t} \frac{g(y_1)}{\sqrt{t^2-\left( y_2^2+(y_1-x)^2 \right)}}dy \\+ \frac{d}{dt}\left\{  \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{|y-x|<t} \frac{f(y_1)}{\sqrt{t^2-\left( y_2^2+(y_1-x)^2 \right)}}dy  \right\}.$$

The ideas I have for this are

1. Changing variables so I am integrating in the variable $x+ry$ over $y\in B_1(0)$ in $0\leq r \leq t$ (might make it easier to differentiate under the integral). But still the integral is not working.
2. Converting to polar somehow, in which case the denominator becomes $\sqrt{t^2-r^2}$, but then the numerator becomes $g(r\cos\theta)$, which is screwy.
3. Somehow using Green's theorem to change it into an integral over the boundary $\{|y-x|=t\}$ and then parameterizing (as in the 3d--> 2d descent). But it's hard to find a primitive.
4. Don't work with this formula at all, and instead try to derive a solution some other way

Any ideas? Of course we should end up with

$$u(x,t) = \frac12 [f(x+t)+f(x-t)] + \frac12 \int_{x-t}^{x+t}g(\xi) d\xi.$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the 2D formula we integrate $g$ over the disk $B(x,t)$ with the weight $(t^2-|y-x|^2)^{-1/2}$. This weight has a peculiar property: every vertical (or horizontal) line segment crossing the disk is equally weighted. To wit (I take $x=0$ to shorten formulas):
$$
\int_{B(0,t)\cap \{y_1=b\}} 
(t^2-|y|^2)^{-1/2} \,dy_2= \int_{-\sqrt{t^2-b^2}}^{\sqrt{t^2-b^2}} (t^2-b^2 - y_2^2)^{-1/2} \,dy_2 = \pi 
$$
independently of $b$ (as long as $|b|<t$).

If $g(y)=g(y_1)$,  we integrate over $y_2$ first,   and get 
$$
\int_{B(x,t) } \frac{g(y)}{ \sqrt{t^2-|y-x|^2}} \,dy 
= \int_{x_1-t}^{x_1+t} g(y_1) \,\pi \,dy
$$
Which, after division by $2\pi$, gives a part of 1D formula.

I leave the other part to you.

Comment: Very helpful, thanks!

Comment: @EricAuid, could you explain me please how we can integreate over $y_2$? i am about $\int_{B(x,t) } \frac{g(y)}{ \sqrt{t^2-|y-x|^2}} \,dy 
= \int_{x_1-t}^{x_1+t} g(y_1) \,\pi \,dy$