# Deduce 1d wave equation from 2d by method of descent(repeating, beacuse i don't understand the asnwer)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

I saw this question [Deduce 1d wave equation from 2d by method of descent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/583941/deduce-1d-wave-equation-from-2d-by-method-of-descent), but I don't understand the answer. If $g(y)=g(y_1)$, we integrate over $y_2$ first, and get
$\int_{B(x,t) } \frac{g(y)}{ \sqrt{t^2-|y-x|^2}} \,dy 
= \int_{x_1-t}^{x_1+t} g(y_1) \,\pi \,dy$. How did we integrate this one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The argument is correct, though the notation is sloppy, which is likely contributing to your confusion. Post No Bulls cut some notation corners. Most particularly, representing two different functions, one with domain in $\Bbb R^2$ and the other with domain in $\Bbb R$, by the same symbol "$g$".

$y = (y_1, y_2)$ is a variable on $\Bbb R^2$. What was meant by "$g(y) = g(y_1)$" is that $g$ is a function on $\Bbb R^2$, which could be written as $g(y_1, y_2)$. But the values are constant as $y_2$ varies. That is, there is some function $\hat g$ on $\Bbb R$ such that for all $y_1, y_2$ in the domain of $g, g(y_1,y_2) = \hat g(y_1)$. Unlike Post No Bulls, I will continue to differentiate between $g$ on $\Bbb R^2$ and $\hat g$ on $\Bbb R$.

Now $x = (x_1, x_2)$ is likewise a variable on $\Bbb R^2$, and $t$ is a variable on $\Bbb R$. $B(x, t)$ is the ball of radius $t$ about $x$. That is, it is the set $$B(x,t) =\{y \mid (y_1 - x_1)^2 + (y_2 - x_2)^2 \le t^2\}$$
In the integral, "$dy$" is a notation for the area differential $dA \equiv dy_1\,dy_2$. Any area integral over a nicely shaped region like a disk can be expressed as iterated integrals:

$$\iint_{B(x,t)}\frac{g(y)}{\sqrt{t^2-|y-x|^2}} \,dy = \int_{x_2-t}^{x_2+t}\left(\int_{x_1 - \sqrt{t^2 - (y_2 - x_2)^2}}^{x_1 + \sqrt{t^2 - (y_2 - x_2)^2}} \frac{\hat g(y_1)}{ \sqrt{t^2-(y_1 - x_1)^2 - (y_2 - x_2)^2}}\,dy_1\right)dy_2$$
and also 
$$\begin{align}\iint_{B(x,t)}\frac{g(y)}{\sqrt{t^2-|y-x|^2}} \,dy &= \int_{x_1-t}^{x_1+t}\left(\int_{x_2 - \sqrt{t^2 - (y_1 - x_1)^2}}^{x_2 + \sqrt{t^2 - (y_1 - x_1)^2}} \frac{\hat g(y_1)}{ \sqrt{t^2-(y_1 - x_1)^2 - (y_2 - x_2)^2}}\,dy_2\right)dy_1\\&= \int_{x_1-t}^{x_1+t}\hat g(y_1)\left(\int_{x_2 - \sqrt{t^2 - (y_1 - x_1)^2}}^{x_2 + \sqrt{t^2 - (y_1 - x_1)^2}} \frac{dy_2}{ \sqrt{t^2-(y_1 - x_1)^2 - (y_2 - x_2)^2}}\right)dy_1\end{align}$$

"Integrate by $y_2$ first" means to use the latter iterated integral formula, where the inside integral is over $y_2$. After pulling the constant $\hat g(y_1)$ out of the inside integral, we get the integral that Post No Bulls had already shown in the first part of the answer is always $\pi$, regardless of $y_1, t$ within the region of interest. Because integration is unchanged by translation, it is easy to see that the integral is constant with respect to $x_1, x_2$ as well. Thus the expression simplifies to $$\iint_{B(x,t)}\frac{g(y)}{\sqrt{t^2-|y-x|^2}} \,dy = \int_{x_1-t}^{x_1+t}\hat g(y_1)(\pi)\, dy_1$$

Comment: Thank you for detailed response